# How to pass pagination parameters with additional params cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.3

I have a list of categories which displays the list of items under it.

Thus:

routes have:

```
Router::connect('/category/:slug', array('controller' => 'Product',
             'action'=>'catview', 'slug'=> '[0-9a-zA-Z]+'));
Router::connect('/category/:slug/:page', array('controller' => 'Product',
             'action'=>'catview','slug'=> '[0-9a-zA-Z]+','page'=>'[0-9]+'));
```

and

when I do this in results page, it just doesn't work:

```
<?php 
        $slug = $this->params['slug'];
        $this->Paginator->options(array('url'=> array('controller' => 'Product',
                             'action'=>'catview','slug'=> $slug)));

        echo $this->Paginator->prev('<< Show me previous', array('class'=>'prev'))
        . $this->Paginator->next('Show me more >>', array('class'=>'next')); ?>
```

It does not change the results, it shows the same result as it does on page 1.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: what url do the nexrt/previous links point at? IME you're better off using get params for pagination variables.

Comment: They are showing `/:slug/:page` as in `/Calculators/2`

Comment: `/Calculators/2` doesn't match either of the routes in the question.

Comment: @AD7six can you please throw some lights on "get params for pagination variables" ?? PS: I don't care if URL looks ugly. I just need the results right but, I am required to put $this->paginate->options URL because I am using a slug else it is redirecting to /controller/action/:page

Comment: [using get params for pagination](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#using-get-parameters-for-pagination) And **please** only tag your question with the version of cake you are using - which is it 2.0 or 2.3?

Comment: Retagged. Ok. My bad, I meant it is giving me `/category/Calculators/2`

Comment: Thanks for the link. I don't exactly get it. Can you frame an answer if you know the solution, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to [AD7six](https://stackoverflow.com/users/761202/ad7six) for the reference.

My controller needs to have :

```
$this->paginate = array(
 //other stuff here
 'paramType' => 'querystring'
);
```

Followed by:

```
$this->Paginator->options(array('url'=> array('controller' => 'Product',
                                  'action'=>'catview','slug'=> $slug),
                                     'convertKeys' => array('page')));
```

in the view file